# Problemas con la base de datos

Tags: php, mysqli

Estoy haciendo un simple `SELECT` y me da este error

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\portfolio\buscador.php on line 79

Al no saber por que salía hice un `mysqli_error();` y me dio esto

> Error description: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Os dejo por aquí el código

```
if (isset($_POST['buscaLocal'])) {

require("../conexionBaseDatos/admin.php");
$sqlBusc = "SELECT l.nombreLo, l.ubicacion, c.valoracion 
FROM locales l 
INNER JOIN comentario c ON l.idLocal = c.idLocal 
WHERE l.nombreLo='$_POST[nombre]' 
OR l.ubicacion = '$_POST[localiz]' OR c.valoracion= $_POST[valorac]";

$datoBusca = mysqli_query($enlace, $sqlBusc);

if (!$enlace -> $datoBusca) {
  echo("Error description: " . $enlace -> error);
}
while($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($datoBusca)){  
    echo "<table class='tablaBusca'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Nombre</th>
                <th>Ubicaci&oacute;n</th>
                <th>Valoraci&oacute;n</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class='lineaTabla'>
            <td class='textoTabla'>$fila[nombre]</td>
            <td class='textoTabla'>$fila[ubicacion]</td>
            <td class='textoTabla'>$fila[valoracion]</td>
            <td class='textoTabla imagen'><a class='botonDetallePaciente' href='#'><i class='fa fa-angle-right'></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>    
</table>";
}
}
```

En la linea 1, 2 y 3 solo hay esto

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="es" class="no-js">
    <head>
```

El resultado del `var_dump`:

```
 string(166) "SELECT l.nombreLo, l.ubicacion, c.valoracion FROM locales l INNER JOIN comentario c ON l.idLocal = c.idLocal WHERE l.nombreLo='' OR l.ubicacion = '' OR c.valoracion= "
```

Comment: peganos un var_dump de  $sqlBusc, por favor

Answer (score 4):

El `var_dump` muestra claramente que no están llegando los datos del `$_POST`:

```
SELECT l.nombreLo, l.ubicacion, c.valoracion 
FROM locales l 
INNER JOIN comentario c ON l.idLocal = c.idLocal 
WHERE l.nombreLo='' OR l.ubicacion = '' OR c.valoracion=
```

En casos como estos conviene siempre evaluar los datos del POST. Esto se puede hacer mediante operadores ternarios, que permiten al mismo tiempo evaluar y guardar el dato en una variable que luego puedes usar para la consulta. Esto aporta también claridad al código.

Por ejemplo:

```
if (isset($_POST['buscaLocal'])) {
    #Evaluamos con un ternario, si está vacío asignamos NULL
    #Si se permiten valores por defecto en alguno de estos campos
    #en vez de NULL pones ese valor por defecto
    $nombre= !empty($_POST["nombre"])  ? $_POST["nombre"]  : NULL;
    $localiz=!empty($_POST["localiz"]) ? $_POST["localiz"] : NULL;
    $valorac=!empty($_POST["valorac"]) ? $_POST["valorac"] : NULL;
    
    #Verificamos que los tres datos fueron llenados
    #Esta parte sólo se ejecutará si hay datos en las tres variables
    #Si alguna es NULL te mostrará el mensaje del else
    #Esto puede adaptarse, según la lógica de tu contexto
    if ($nombre && $localiz && $valorac) {
        #El require aquí, porque estamos seguros de usar la consulta
        require("../conexionBaseDatos/admin.php");
        #Nótese que usamos las variables
        $sqlBusc = "SELECT l.nombreLo, l.ubicacion, c.valoracion 
                    FROM locales l 
                    INNER JOIN comentario c ON l.idLocal = c.idLocal 
                    WHERE l.nombreLo='$nombre' 
                    OR l.ubicacion = '$localiz' OR c.valoracion= $valorac";
        #Aquí el resto del código
        
    } else {
        echo "Hay datos vacíos en el post. Revise el llenado de datos";    
    }
#Esto cierra el if del isset
}
```

He puesto comentarios pertinentes. Si hay algo que no entiendes puedes preguntar en comentarios. Espero te sirva.

### ¿Por qué los datos llegan vacíos?

Debes controlar en el cliente (formulario u otro) que se estén posteando tres datos con las claves `nombre`, `localiz` y `valorac`. Si tienes un formulario éste debe tener en el `name` de los respectivos elementos esos tres valores. Si pasas los datos por Ajax lo mismo, el objeto que pasas debe tener esas tres claves y lo mismo si pasas los datos por URL.

---

> **NOTA SOBRE LA SEGURIDAD:**
>
> Tu forma de lanzar la consulta conlleva un grave riesgo de seguridad
> conocido como ***Inyección SQL***. Un usuario mal intencionado puede
> manipular los datos del POST para ejecutar código dañino en tu
> sistema. Deberías blindar el código usando **consultas preparadas**.
> Cuando sea posible infórmate sobre el tema.

Answer (score 2):

No estás concatenando las variables php, intenta esto:

```
$sqlBusc = "SELECT l.nombreLo, l.ubicacion, c.valoracion FROM locales l INNER JOIN comentario c ON l.idLocal = c.idLocal WHERE l.nombreLo='".$_POST[nombre]."' OR l.ubicacion = '".$_POST[localiz]."' OR c.valoracion= ".$_POST[valorac]."";
```

Comment: No, no funciona sale el mismo error

Comment: Correcto, lo que haces se puede hacer si solo son nombres de variables, pero si entra en juego otras cosas hay que concaternar. +1

Comment: Eso te petara, tiene una doble comilla de mas

Comment: Haz un var_dump($sqlBusc); exit; despues del select y muestranos que sale. ¿Sigue saliendo el mismo resultado que antes?

Comment: Lo ha puesto arriba

Comment: Si, lo ha puesto antes... Pero el contenido del select ha cambiado con las concatenaciones. Y la doble comilla es para indicar que termina el select junto a una concatenación, finalmente hay numero de comillas pares (8).

Comment: Fergush el problema es que la ultima condicion del where viene en blanco, si fuera un string no importa, seria algo como ....where x = '' (dos comillas simples), esto no es problema, pero ....where x =  (nada) si es un problema, pues la query esta incompleta

Answer (score 2):

Al final de la query, el ultimo valor, al ser un integer no le pones comillas, pero este viene vacio, lo que la sentencia queda incompleta, agrega unas comillas y listo.

Quedaria asi:

```
$sqlBusc = "SELECT l.nombreLo, l.ubicacion, c.valoracion FROM locales l INNER JOIN comentario c ON l.idLocal = c.idLocal WHERE l.nombreLo='".$_POST[nombre]."' OR l.ubicacion = '".$_POST[localiz]."' OR c.valoracion= '".$_POST[valorac]."'";
```

Comment: $_POST['valoracion'] es un int, no un string por lo que no va entre comillas.

Comment: es totalmente indiferente, puede probarlo. si no lo que puedes hacer es asegurarte que el valor no llegue nunca vacio.

Comment: Tenias razón, ahora ya me funciona, muchas gracias.

Comment: que te funcione no quiere decir que esté bien, mejor manda un NULL o un 0, saludos.

Comment: Si lo suyo es que controle que no llegue vacio, o cambiar el valor de vacio a otro. a NULL no es conveniente, ya que si esta haciendo el where con NULL pueden darse muchisisisismos registros (entendiendo que al tener un OR en el where los campos pueden ser NULL)